# Как лучше работать с динамическими UI объектами в MVVM

Tags: c#, gui, mvvm, ui, design

Добрый день. У меня такой вопрос, как лучше сделать динамически-создаваемые контролы на MVVM, то-есть как лучше спроектировать UI интерфейс?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам и в самом деле нужны **динамические**, во время выполнения создаваемые контролы? Опишите свою реальную задачу.

Comment: Ну на самом деле я хотел бы сделать пародию на unreal engine blueprint, но совсем для других целей, но с похожим по принципу работы интерфейсу (вот видео https://youtu.be/kmnC6IUPGjI). Это чтобы долго не объяснять и не запутать.

Comment: Эээ, любое объяснение будет короче, чем 13 минут видео. И вопрос не в технической стороне, появляющиеся-исчезающие кнопки можно сделать сотней различных способов. Вопрос в том, какую сущность вы хотите показать юзеру. От этого и только от этого зависит, какой способ правильный.

Comment: А можно как нибудь в лс написать? :)

Comment: Как это "сущность"?

Comment: (1) Не, ЛС нету, но можно открыть чат, если хотите. (2) Сущность? Ну, вы ж показываете юзеру не кнопку и тексбокс на самом деле, а билет на концерт. Или историю болезни слона. Или заказ цветов для тёщи. Или список знакомых, у которых день рожденья сегодня. Это и есть реальный объект, который вы абстрагируете вашим UI.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42879/discussion-between-alex-rudenkiy-and-vladd).

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListViewModel}">
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextViewModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ButtonViewModel}">
      <Button Content="{Binding Caption}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Где модели представления имеют следующий вид:

```
class MainViewModel
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    Content = new ListViewModel
    (
      new TextViewModel() { Text = "Нажми кнопку" },
      new ButtonViewModel() { Caption = "Жмакни меня" }
    );
  }

  public object Content { get; }
}

class ListViewModel
{
  public ListViewModel(params object[] items)
  {
    Items = items;
  }

  public IEnumerable<object> Items { get; }
}

class TextViewModel
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

class ButtonViewModel
{
  public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

PS: Только учтите, что генерация представления, это достаточно медленная операция. И если вы планируете на лету генерировать и изменять сложные интерфейсы - вы получите тормоза. Выгоднее сгенерировать один раз на все случаи жизни, и просто скрывать не нужное.